# Setting a timezone doesn't give what I'm expecting

Tags: java, timezone

I must say that working with timezones is my nemesis!

In my DB(PostGres) I have a field of type "timestamp without time" zone.

The value I save in it is in UTC time.

What I want to do is displaying the value according to the default timezone of my machine.

So, when I retrieve the value from the DB I first have to "say" that this is a UTC time and therefore I set its time zone to UTC:

```
private Date lastUpdateToUTC( Date myDate)
{
    if ( myDate!= null )
    {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" );
        dateFormat.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "UTC" ) );

        System.out.println("orig: " + dateFormat.format(myDate));

        try
        {
            Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse( dateFormat.format( myDate) );

            dateFormat.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getDefault( ) );

            System.out.println("converted: " + dateFormat.format(convertedDate));

            return dateFormat.parse( dateFormat.format( convertedDate ) );
            ....
```

Let say myDate is 2013-08-05 10:44:08.

What I'm expecting is that the first output is 2013-08-05 10:44:08 and the second 2013-08-05 12:44:08.

Instead I get 2013-08-05 08:44:08 and 2013-08-05 10:44:08...

Where is my error in reasoning?
What should I do to have what I'm expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.util.Date doesn't support timezone.

For the first output, you set dateFormat to UTC.  When you provide the Date to dateFormat, it converts it to UTC.  It has no way of knowing which  timezone your Date is, it assumes it's local timezone.  So looks like in your case it's GMT+2, dateFormat subtracts 2 to make it UTC.
Then you do format - parse, which should not have any affect, then you change timezone to your local timezone and print your original Date value.  (This time w/o any conversion).

Answer (score 1):

Your current local timezone is `GMT+2`, that's why the first output would be `T+2` hours.
In order to print the date in UTC timezone, the date will minus 2 hours because of `+2` hour offset.

```
intput: 2013-08-05 10:44:08      // GMT+2 timezone
orig: 2013-08-05 08:44:08        // UTC timezone
converted: 2013-08-05 10:44:08   // default timezone: GMT+2 timezone
```

You can print the current local timezone to know the offset using `dateFormat.getTimeZone()`. 
Take myself as an example, my local timezone is `GMT+8`, the offset would be `8 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 28800000` milliseconds.

```
System.out.println("My Current Timezone: " + dateFormat.getTimeZone());
// My Current Timezone: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Taipei",offset=28800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=42,lastRule=null]
```